# Center Checkboxes in Table Layout Panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox, tablelayout

I'm trying to center my checkboxes in a `TableLayoutPanel`, but they always end up looking left-aligned due to the nature of the checkbox control. See picture below:

[image: Table Layout Picture]

I want each rows checks to be left-aligned, but for it to appear more centered. Something like the following:

[image: Table Layout Centered]

I've checked around online, and I can center the checkboxes by setting `AnchorStyles.None` which is not what I want, because then the checkboxes are not aligned. I have them set to `Dock.Fill` so you can click anywhere in the cell to activate the checkbox.

I'm currently just padding my table to achieve a similar effect, but it's by far not an acceptable solution long-term. Also, padding the cells will line break the checkbox text without taking up all the available space on the row (since some of the row is being eaten by padding). The same goes for using a spacer-cell on the left of the table, not an ideal solution.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you:

1. Set all the `ColumnStyles` of your `TableLayoutPanel` as `.SizeType = SizeType.AutoSize`.
2. Set your `TableLayoutPanel.AutoSize = true` and `TableLayoutPanel.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink`;
3. Add this code to center your checkboxes (as well as your `TableLayoutPanel`) dynamically:

   ```
   //SizeChanged event handler of your tableLayoutPanel1
   private void tableLayoutPanel1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
      //We just care about the horizontal position
      tableLayoutPanel1.Left = (tableLayoutPanel1.Parent.Width - tableLayoutPanel1.Width)/2;
      //you can adjust the vertical position if you need.
   }
   ```

### UPDATE

As for your added question, I think we have to change some things:

1. Set your `CheckBox` `AutoSize` to false. The solution before requires it to be `true`.
2. Add more code (beside the code above):

   ```
    int checkWidth = CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize(yourCheckBox.CreateGraphics(),System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.MixedNormal).Width;
    //TextChanged event handler of your CheckBoxes (used for all the checkBoxes)
    private void checkBoxes_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
      UpdateCheckBoxSize((CheckBox)sender);
    }
    //method to update the size of CheckBox, the size is changed when the CheckBox's Font is bolded and AutoSize = true.
    //However we set AutoSize = false and we have to make the CheckBox wide enough
    //to contain the bold version of its Text.
    private void UpdateCheckBoxSize(CheckBox c){
       c.Width = TextRenderer.MeasureText(c.Text, new Font(c.Font, FontStyle.Bold)).Width + 2 * checkWidth;
    }
    //initially, you have to call UpdateCheckBoxSize
    //this code can be placed in the form constructor
    foreach(CheckBox c in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
       UpdateCheckBoxSize(c);

    //add this to make your CheckBoxes centered even when the form containing tableLayoutPanel1 resizes
    //This can also be placed in the form constructor
    tableLayoutPanel1.Parent.SizeChanged += (s,e) => {
       tableLayoutPanel1.Left = (tableLayoutPanel1.Parent.Width - tableLayoutPanel1.Width)/2;
    };
   ```

Comment: This is working best so far, but I would have one more riddle for you: Suppose the checkboxes become bold when the user rolls over them. This shifts the checkboxes around to make room for their new, bolded, size. How can I essentially force the cell size to the future, possible, bolded size so that they don't "wiggle around" when the user rolls over them?

Comment: It's better, but it's still skewed to the left. Thankfully, the bold no longer shifts the checkboxes. Thanks for all the help, and although it isn't perfect it IS better than what I had... 
http://i.imgur.com/S9SjAcL.png

Comment: @DTI-Matt it's easy to fix it, the code I posted center the `tableLayoutPanel1`, it requirest the checkboxes (on the same row) have the same `Text length`. If you change the code in `tableLayoutPanel1_SizeChanged`, you can achieve what you want. The point is instead of `tableLayoutPanel1.Width`, you have to get the `Width` of the total text length of 2 checkboxes on the same row, you can update this `Width` in the `UpdateCheckBoxSize(...)` method... I hope you get the idea.

Comment: @DTI-Matt also, it's not centered if your `checkBoxes` in the column 1 and column 2 have much difference in `textlength`, the new code have to make room for the `bolded` version and the longer the text is, the more room the checkbox needs. If correct the layout so that you  can see the checkboxes centered (with normal font), the text may be clipped out when your mouse is over it (meaning bolded-font text doesn't have enough room to display). I think you can try changing the color instead of `font-weight` when mouse is over.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having the checkboxes in cells, having each one inside a panel all inside a groupbox will allow the checkboxes to fill each panel and have a click able area around them.  then with the groupbox dock set to fill and the panels' anchors set to top,bottom they all stay centered.